# Problems declaring foreign keys, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a table called Enrollments with two attributes that reference the foreign keys of another table. The schema for Enrollments is:

[image]

I'm trying to make `SectionNo` and `Year` of `Enrollments` reference `SectionNo` and `Year` of the `CourseSections` table (already created). Here is the schema for that relation:

[image]

Here is how I'm trying to add the foreign key constraints when I create the enrollments table:

[image]

I'm getting the error:

> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[CourseSections]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

Comment: your foreign key must match the primary key of the referenced table ... if you have more column in that primary key (like year, semester) it will not work

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn I don't want any SectionNos showing up in Enrollments that aren't in CourseSections. I understand my mistake, but how can I ensure this constraint holds if I can't use a foreign key? I can't make SectionNo and Year as candidate keys

Comment: you cannot reference only a part of the unique primary key of the parent table ... because that part might not be unique ... so it might not clear which record is referenced by your foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Make SectionNo and Year as candidate keys.

Comment: @Adam: if you can't make (`SectionNo`, `Year`) unique or a primary key - then you just cannot reference those two columns as a foreign key.

Comment: @marc_s is there a way I can have this kind of effect though? I don't want a SectionNo showing up in Enrollments unless it is in CourseSections. What is the thinking behind the "foreign keys must be unique" anyway?

Comment: @Adam: if you have a foreign key referencing another table - it ***MUST*** be unique, otherwise you would end up referencing multiple rows and this just doesn't work .... e.g. if you have a "country code" and the value you have referencing multiple countries - which one are you really referencing now??

Comment: @marc_s Say I had two relations that include as an attribute a list of first names. The names aren't necessarily unique, but I want to make sure that no name in relation B exists that isn't in relation A. Is the only way I could make this work via a trigger or assertion something? it sounds like foreign keys can't be used at all in a case like that.

Comment: A foreign key **must** reference a unique list of possible values to ensure referential integrity. So yes - either you'd have to have a separate table with a list of the unique possible values for first name - or you cannot use a foreign key to enforce your requirement

Comment: @AnoopLL Alright. If I want to get similar functionality though, eg even though attribute A and B aren't unique I only want values in A to appear that are in B, what can I do? Should I use a trigger?

Comment: @Adam yeah or you can use a sub-query to check the values exist in another relation.